# Why am I obtaining this ModelMapper mapping errors converting a Set of an many to many Hibernate field of an entity into Set field of the DTO class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, modelmapper

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate mapping and I have the following problem.

I have this **Project** entity class:

package com.fivebits.gestionale.model.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.Temporal;
import jakarta.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "project_name", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;
    
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String projectCode;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Column(name = "budget", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal budget;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "project_supplier",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    )
    private Set<Supplier> suppliers = new HashSet<>();

    // Altri campi e metodi getter/setter

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }
    
    

    public String getProjectCode() {
        return projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectCode(String projectCode) {
        this.projectCode = projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDate getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    public void setBudget(BigDecimal budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    
    


    public Set<Supplier> getSuppliers() {
        return suppliers;
    }

    public void setSuppliers(Set<Supplier> suppliers) {
        this.suppliers = suppliers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project [id=" + id + ", projectName=" + projectName + ", description=" + description + ", startDate="
                + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", budget=" + budget + ", client=" + client + "]";
    }
    
      
}
```

and the related DTO class:

```
package com.fivebits.gestionale.model.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProjectDTO {

    private long id;
    private String projectName;
    private String projectCode;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private BigDecimal budget;
    private ClientDTO client;
    private Set<Supplier> suppliers;

}
```

It seems that I have a problem converting this field of the entity class:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "project_supplier",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
)
private Set<Supplier> suppliers = new HashSet<>();
```

into this field of the related DTO class:

```
private Set<Supplier> suppliers;
```

Infact running this test method:

```
@Test
void getProjectByIdTest() {
    
    List<ProjectDTO> projectsList = projectService.getProjectsList();
    
    ProjectDTO result = projectService.getProjectById(projectsList.get(0).getId());
    
    assertTrue(result != null);
    
    assertTrue(result.getSuppliers() != null);

    //assertTrue(result.getProjectName().equals("Progetto di Test"));
    
}
```

when it try to perform the first operation that try to retrieve the list of Project that is related to the conversion of this field:

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@3ad5f99 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:386)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:80)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:589)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:422)
    at com.fivebits.gestionale.service.ProjectServiceImpl.lambda$0(ProjectServiceImpl.java:44)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at com.fivebits.gestionale.service.ProjectServiceImpl.getProjectsList(ProjectServiceImpl.java:44)
    at com.fivebits.gestionale.service.ProjectServiceTest.getProjectByIdTest(ProjectServiceTest.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.fivebits.gestionale.model.entity.Project.suppliers: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:151)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.util.Iterables.getLength(Iterables.java:50)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:44)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:31)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:306)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:109)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:245)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:151)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:114)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:71)
    ... 82 more
```

What is wrong in my code? How can I correctly convert the Set field of the entity class into a Set field of the related DTO class?

Comment: the error tells you that at the point when you try to access the suppliers via the `getSuppliers()` method your entity is no longer attached to a session (not actively connected to a database). And because the suppliers relation is lazily fetched it isn't automatically done in the original query. You either need to change the fetch type of your relation to `FetchType.EAGER` or modify your query so that the relation is always directly fetched with the main entity.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS tnx, if you put it as answer I will accept it